# How to create cross-references in a Mail Merge

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, labels, letters

When I wanted to make a mail merge in which I used `\label{}` and `\footref{}` I got the warning `There were multiply-defined labels` and also the reference pointed to the last label with the same name.

I searched for solutions but didn't find any. Here my code:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=10cm, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\parindent 0pt                  % no space for the first line of a paragraph

% ---------- informations to read from the file ---------
\def\chopline#1,#2,#3 \\{       % number of arguments per line
    \def\salutation{#1}         % Sir/Mrs
    \def\firstname{#2\xspace}
    \def\lastname{#3\xspace}
}

\newif\ifmore                   % defines a new "if" of the name "more"
\moretrue                       % sets more to true

\begin{document}

\newread\source                 % creates a new variable "source"
\openin\source=path/datas.csv   % opens a data file

\loop                           % runs until the end of file (EOF)
    \read\source to \line       % reads every line
    \ifeof\source               % in the case the EOF is reached
        \global\morefalse       % setzt more auf false
    \else
        \expandafter\chopline\line\\    % breaks datas into lines

        Dear \salutation \lastname,

        \bigskip
        here is the first Information\footnote{\label{fn:informations}special informations} and then we want to show another one\footnote{another information}.
        \newpage        
        After that we reference back to the first one\footref{fn:informations}.

        \setcounter{footnote}{0}% resets counter for footnotes to zero
    \fi                         % end of if-else
\ifmore\newpage\repeat          % creates a new site and goes back to loop
\closein\source                 % closes data file

\end{document}
```

The `datas.csv` has the following content:

```
Mr., James, Bond
Mrs., Ada, Lovelace
```

The problem is, that the second call of the first footnote `\footref{fn:informations}` in James' mail points to the reference of Ada's mail.

Comment: What is a "serie letter"?

Comment: In german you call it Serienbrief. I guess "Mail merge" is the correct translation, isn't it?

Comment: What exactly is the question or the problem?

Comment: The problem was, that the references didn't work properly., because many times `\label{fn:informations}` was created and the hyperlink of the mail to the first person referenced to the label of the last person's mail.

Comment: And what is the problem/question now?

Comment: btw, thanks for the feedback.
The code example from above now works. I couldn't find any solution in the internet -- not in english (maybe because of my wrong translation) nor in german.
I just wanted to share my solution. I should have made it more clear.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the site guidelines to understand the way the Q&A format works. In this case, please split your post into a question and answer and post the answer in the answer space. Right now, it is just confusing as there is no question in the question. You can then accept your own answer so your question is not listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got the idea to give to every label not only the name but also a number, which will be increased every time.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=10cm, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\Label}[1]{\label{#1\number\PersonNo}}
\newcommand{\Footref}[1]{\footref{#1\number\PersonNo}}

\parindent 0pt                  % no space for the first line of a paragraph

% ---------- informations to read from the file ---------
\def\chopline#1,#2,#3 \\{       % number of arguments per line
    \def\salutation{#1}         % Sir/Mrs
    \def\firstname{#2\xspace}
    \def\lastname{#3\xspace}
}

\newcount\PersonNo              % counter for each person, it is necessary, that no label is created twice
\PersonNo=0                     % starts with zero

\newif\ifmore                   % defines a new "if" of the name "more"
\moretrue                       % sets more to true

\begin{document}

\newread\source                 % creates a new variable "source"
\openin\source=path/datas.csv   % opens a data file

\loop                           % runs until the end of file (EOF)
    \read\source to \line       % reads every line
    \ifeof\source               % in the case the EOF is reached
        \global\morefalse       % setzt more auf false
    \else
        \expandafter\chopline\line\\    % breaks datas into lines

        Dear \salutation \lastname,

        \bigskip
        here is the first Information\footnote{\Label{fn:informations}special informations} and then we want to show another one\footnote{another information}.
        \newpage        
        After that we reference back to the first one\Footref{fn:informations}.

        \setcounter{footnote}{0}% resets counter for footnotes to zero
        \advance\PersonNo by 1  % increases person counter by 1
    \fi                         % end of if-else
\ifmore\newpage\repeat          % creates a new site and goes back to loop
\closein\source                 % closes data file

\end{document}
```

Now every label is unique, because of the combination of name and number. You just create and refer to the labels via: `\Label{name}` and `\Footref{name}`.